# Is there a way to tell which pip packages are using C++ bindings?

Tags: python, c++, virtualenv, conda

Pretty much what the title says. I am in a virtualenv / conda env and I want to figure out which of the packages are using C/C++ bindings in order to investigate a memory leak. Is there a way to do this quickly?

Comment: Quite old but always useful http://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/ or https://benbernardblog.com/tracking-down-a-freaky-python-memory-leak/

Comment: On linux you can simply inspect the memory maps of your `python` process (`/proc/$PID/maps`) to see which `.so` files are loaded. Their paths or filenames should give a hint to which extension they belong to.